# Talend Open Studio : Stored Procedure Returning null

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, talend

I am trying to implement a solution as below:

```
tJava -> tMSSQLRow (Which calls "exec <Stored Procedure> <input parameter>") -> tParseRecordSet -> tJavaFlex
```

The same SP works fine on Management Studio, as well as, Talend Sandbox; and returns the data.

But, somehow, it's not working in Talend Open Studio. And it's returning null.

Could someone provide some solution to that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use tMSSQLRow instead of tMSSqlSP to call the procedure?

Based on your job, the design should be:
`tJava --> tMSSqlSP --> tParseRecordSet --> tJavaFlex`
tMSSqlSP schema must have a column of datatype "Object".

Why does it works using Talend Big Data Sandbox? That is the question.

TRF